# How to Write User's IP in Html Page as Comment

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, ip, comments

I saw this magic in [www.illuminat.org](http://www.illuminat.org) Rightnow, the site is not online.

*When a user visited this page and press ctrl+U for viewving site source,
user just see his/her computer ip address with a location info in comment tags... --I don't know how to the site do it-- If user scrolldown a little bit, `<html>...` codes came up...*

Anyway, sorry for my english, but I think you understand me,

How can I do that in Asp.net MVC3 Razor C# application ?

Comment: you need to split this in two parts. Writing a comment and detecting request host IP address. Which one of these you are unable to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your controller you can set a ViewBag property

```
ViewBag.VisitorIp = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

then in your view include the following HTML:

```
<!-- 
 Your IP: @ViewBag.VisitorIp
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

depends is it in your viewbag? if so

ViewBag.IP = 192.168.0.1

Comment: <!-- @Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] -->

Comment: Instead of commenting on your own answer, you can (and should) edit your answer to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

normally that is just put before the code of the page with lots of line spaces to fool people into thinking the source is hidden.

Sadly there is no way to hide HTML source code on a machine